# I am trying to convert ppt to jpg using aspose, but the jpg is of very low quality

Tags: python, aspose

```
  def convert_ppt_to_img():
    ppt_path = file_path
    
    ppt_name = os.path.basename(ppt_path)
    img_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'PPT_IMG')
    os.makedirs(img_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
    # Open PowerPoint application
    pres = slides.Presentation(ppt_path)
    for index in range(pres.slides.length):
        # Get reference of slide
        slide = pres.slides[index]

        # Save as JPG
        slide.get_thumbnail().save(os.path.join(img_dir, f'slide_{index}.jpg'), drawing.imaging.ImageFormat.jpeg)


    print('Images saved successfully in', img_dir)
```

how to make sure that all the images are of high quality, the images are of very low quality, also i couldn't find any appropriate solution in the docs, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Aspose.Slides for Python does not currently provide a feature to manage the quality of JPG images converted from presentation slides.

By default, images are saved at a small size, and output images are of very low quality. You can [change the size of images](https://docs.aspose.com/slides/python-net/convert-powerpoint-to-jpg/) like this:

```py
size = drawing.Size(1920, 1080)
...
slide.get_thumbnail(size).save(os.path.join(img_dir, f'slide_{index}.jpg'), drawing.imaging.ImageFormat.jpeg)
```

Output images look fine.

Alternatively, you can scale the images using the scale parameters.